# In IONIC 3 - "ionic cordova run android" and "ionic cordova build android" give error

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using Ionic 3, When i am trying to execute "ionic cordova run android",its give below error, please help me to resolve this issue -

```
[16:13:25]  dev server running: http://localhost:8101/

[ERROR] app-scripts serve unexpectedly failed.settings: undefinedcontext: [object Object]


    C:\DevArea\IonicApp\MyApp>cordova run android
    ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\kavita.verma1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131
    Subproject Path: CordovaLib
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
    Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistName(PathAssembler.java:84)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.PathAssembler.getDistribution(PathAssembler.java:40)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Install.java:44)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:107)
            at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
```

---

Ionic version

```
    C:\DevArea\IonicApp\MyApp>ionic -v
    3.4.0
```

Comment: what is the output for `cordova requirements` ?

Comment: Requirements check results for android:
Java JDK: installed 1.8.0
Android SDK: installed true
Android target: not installed
cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.android.prefs.AndroidLocation.getAvdFolder()Ljava/lang/St
ring;
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.run(AvdManagerCli.java:210)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.AvdManagerCli.main(AvdManagerCli.java:200)
Gradle: installed C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-3.2\bin\gradle
Error: Some of requirements check failed

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include any additional information you have to your question. Avoid adding this in the comments, as they are harder to read and can be deleted easier. The edit button for your post is just below the post's tags.

Comment: which is your android sdk version?

Answer (score 1):

Delete `.gradle` in userdata.
*Ex*: `C:\Users\admin\.gradle`

Then try again:

```
ionic cordova run android
```

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the node_modules folder

and run

```
npm install
```

or Reinstall Ionic to latest version

Answer (score 0):

Check your platforms with

```
cordova platform ls
```

If android is not installed uses command bellow and try again.

```
cordova platform add android@6.0.0
```